# Pointless [discriminant] tag

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-reorganization

We have [discriminant](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discriminant) with 35 Qs, no wiki excerpt, and unclear scope, that nevertheless has a synonym: [discrimination](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discrimination).

At least half of the threads should be re-tagged to [discriminant-analysis](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discriminant-analysis). The other half seems to be about [classification](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/classification) in general and does not require a separate tag.

Any comments?

Comment: You have a valid point it; I agree with the suggestion to delete it. ([Mandatory disclaimer link](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4641) )

Comment: @usεr11852 Thanks for the feedback :) I will get rid of the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have eliminated the tag.$\;\;\;$